# How to open page in new tab on selecting an item from Dropdown in code behind

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am having a drop down with some values which are binded from Database. When i select a particular option i would to open the corresponding page in new tab i write the following which doesn't work so can any one help me

```
protected void ddlAuthoritytype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string ddl = ddlAuthoritytype.SelectedValue;
switch (ddl)
{
  case "AL":
  Response.Write("<script>Window.Open('alabama-state-tax-calculator.aspx');</script>");`
}
}
```

Comment: did ddlAuthoritytype dropdown nested in an UpdatePanel?

Comment: yes i am using update panle and dropdown nested in an UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
protected void ddlAuthoritytype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var port = Request.Url.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + Request.Url.Port.ToString();

    string ddl = ddlAuthoritytype.SelectedValue;
    switch (ddl)
    {
        case "AL":
            var script = string.Format("window.open('{0}://{1}{2}{3}')", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, port, ResolveUrl("~/alabama-state-tax-calculator.aspx"));
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newWindow",script, true);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you welcome. be warned for future that javascript is case sensitive language. So the Window.Open string in javascript will cause an error

Comment: jsut replace 'var' keyword with string

Comment: in case if i didn't use AJAX but still i would like to achieve the same then how can i

Answer (score 2):

you should use the following script:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--

function openWindowFromDropDownList(theURL,winName,features)

{ 

var SID = document.forms[0].dropdownlist1.value
if (SID > 0){
theURL = theURL + document.forms[0].dropdownlist1.value
    var newWin = window.open(theURL,winName,features);
    newWin.opener = self;
  }
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want a postback and process the change on the server right? Does ddlAuthoritytype have its autopostback property set?

Have you tried doing a Response.Redirect in the switch instead of injecting script?

Edit: Ah, missed the new tab part, now I see why the script.